# Compare fields with exactly the same name

Tags: awk, comparison, field, diff, comm

I would like to find the same elements in the first field of two files. I am familiar with the awk command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' file1 file2
```

But, this does not work if a field contains multi-word expressions that contain one common element. For example, my file1 is:

```
blue and red    20.5
red and green   13.4
yellow and black    10
blue and black  17.2
black and green 21
```

And my file2 is:

```
blue and yellow 18
red and green   11.9
yellow and orange   8
brown and black 6.9
organge and yellow  17
```

The above command will produce the following list:

```
blue and red    20.5
red and green   13.4
yellow and black    10
brown and black 6.9
```

And I would like to have an exact match only

```
red and green   13.4
```

Comment: if they are always the first 3 columns, you should do `[$1 FS $2 FS $3]` if it is dynamic, you should provide the rule, to separate them and the value. Is it the `space before the first number char`?

Comment: Are you using `mawk`, `gawk` or what?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear from my question, but there are only two columns - tab separated. The first column contain names (blue and green, yellow and green, etc) and the second numbers. I would like to identify only those columns with exactly the same name.

Comment: I'm using awk and gawk.

Comment: @Kent Actually `[$1 FS $2 FS $3]` is better written as `[$1,$2,$3]`. The `,` uses a non-printing character (`\034`) to separate the `keys`.

Comment: @jaypal yes, for this question `$1,$2` works.  when we need populate and ouput the key, `$1 FS $2` would be better, we do this quite often. like `for(i in a)print i...` . So I just always write in that way. But you are right for the `[$1,$2]`

Comment: @Kent Yea, for the ones you mentioned I just set `SUBSEP=FS` in the `BEGIN` block or to whatever delimiter I need in the output. `:)`

Comment: @jaypal to be honest, I never used `SUBSEP`, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data are `tab` separated, you should let awk know about that, otherwise, awk cannot work on those data correctly.

try this:

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' file1 file2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your tip.